# Does an app exist to allow mobile control of Velux windows?

Tags: home-automation

We live in a rental apartment and we have several windows by Velux controlled with [homecontrol-io](http://www.velux.com/solutions/products-and-solutions/home-automation).

Is there an accessory that performs as a gateway and allows to control the windows with a smartphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the bottom of your linked page it talks about using your smartphone (http://www.velux.com/solutions/products-and-solutions/home-automation#io_homecontrol)